# prepared statement using bindValue not working

Tags: php, prepared-statement, bindvalue

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to get a prepared statement to work. Its for my final year project at university and I remember reading that prepared statements are good practice and also good for SQL injections. However the following code gives me a Server 500 error.

```
<?php
    $email = "blah@blah.co.uk";
    $hash = "somerandomhashedpassword";
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1234", "UEAnetwork");    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Students (Email, Password) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $email);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $hash);           
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "You have registered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
    }
?>
```

If I run the following then a row is inserted, so I'm pretty sure I'm connecting to the database properly.

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1234", "UEAnetwork");    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Students (Email, Password) VALUES ('blah@blah.co.uk','somerandomhashedpassword')";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);         
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "You have registered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
    }
?>
```

Am I using `bindValue` incorrectly? I've seen it used this way in many tutorials online but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I think you're confusing PDO syntax with mysqli - PDO uses bindValue, whereas mysqli uses bind_param - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, and it works in a slightly different manner.

Comment: The use of a proper IDE would have solved it for you easily.

Comment: One way to troubleshoot this easily is to write your prepared statement or at least the parameter values to a log file to see what it is fetching.  I dont know the syntax for this in PHP.  In C# you can use ```System.IO.File.AppendAllText```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysqli` has a very different API than `PDO`.  There is no `mysql_stmt::bindValue`.  You want to use `mysql_stmt::bind_param`, but the syntax is quite different:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $hash);
```