# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindvalue()

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this below code.
I get  this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindvalue() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyMind2\function.php on line 28

when I run it

```
<?php
class  Main{
    //fetching posts from database
    public function posts(){
        global $conn;
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts`,`users` WHERE userId = user_id_p ORDER BY `post_id` DESC");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
    //add new post if user post 
    public function add_post($user_id,$status,$file_parh){
        global $conn; 
        if(empty($file_parh)){
            $file_parh = 'NULL';
        }
        $query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `user_id_p`, `status`, `status_image`, `status_time`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?,?,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');
        $query->bindValue(1,$user_id);
        $query->bindValue(2,$status);
        $query->bindValue(3,$file_parh);
        $query->execute();
        header('Location: home.php?id='.$_POST['email']);
    }
    //fetch user data by user id 
    public function user_data($user_id){
        global $conn;
        $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = ?');

        //Line 28 below

        $query->bindvalue(1,$user_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571867/prepared-statement-using-bindvalue-not-working Manual - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prepared statement using bindValue not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571867/prepared-statement-using-bindvalue-not-working)

Comment: As a general style - don't use `global`, in this case look at dependency injection and pass the connection into the constructor, or each method if you prefer.

Comment: It seems the code in these functions was written for PDO, which has `bindValue` and `fetchAll` methods on PDOStatement, however the connection was made using mysqli, which doesn't.